# Issue using itemgetter on a nested list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I am trying to arrange this nested list in ascending order by special number. I have tried using itemgetter but I received a typerror. Not too sure what the solution is here. thank you!

```
from operator import itemgetter

nested = [
   [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'AA', 'Special number': 0.1}], 
   [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'BB', 'Special number': 0.15}],
   [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'CC', 'Special number': 0.05}]
]

print(nested.sort(key=itemgetter('Special number')))
```

The error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Can you provide your expected sorted result for that example?

Comment: im expecting the three nested lists to be arranged in ascending order by the "special number" key. So; 'Special number': 0.05,  'Special number': 0.1,  'Special number': 0.15

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `print(sorted(nested, key=lambda x: x[1]['Special number']))`

What you had previously did not work because you were trying to index each list using the string. However what you really want is the the "Special number" field from the dictionary which is the second item for each list.
This translates to `[1]['Special number']`.

Result:

```
[[{'ask price': 8, 'time': 5}, {'ID': 'CC', 'Special number': 0.05}],
 [{'ask price': 8, 'time': 5}, {'ID': 'AA', 'Special number': 0.1}],
 [{'ask price': 8, 'time': 5}, {'ID': 'BB', 'Special number': 0.15}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could compose two operator.itemgetter functions.

```
import operator

nested = [
   [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'AA', 'Special number': 0.1}], 
   [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'BB', 'Special number': 0.15}],
   [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'CC', 'Special number': 0.05}]
]

one = operator.itemgetter(1)
special = operator.itemgetter('Special number')

nested.sort(key=lambda x: special(one(x)))

print(nested)
```

Comment: This reverses the indices from left to right to right to left, making it much harder to read correctly. The whole point of `itemgetter` is to avoir `lambda`; if you're going to use `lambda`, then there is not much point using `itemgetter`, and you can just write `nested.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]['Special number'])`. Note how `[1]` is on the left of `['Special number']`, whereas you had it the other way around as `special(one(x))` with `special` on the left and `one` on the right.

Comment: I agree that nesting/composing itemgetter callables is less than ideal. I like itemgetter mainly for the ability to define it once and assign it to a descriptive name - but then you can do that with a regular function.

Comment: However, verbally it sounds OK ... get Special Number from item one, or calling special number on item one

Answer (score 2):

Since `operator.itemgetter` doesn't know what to do with nested structures, let's write our own `nested_itemgetter`:

```py
def nested_itemgetter(*path):
    def browse(xs):
        for i in path:
            xs = xs[i]
        return xs
    return browse
```

Then you can use `nested_itemgetter(1, 'Special number')` as the sorting key:

```py
nested = [
   [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'AA', 'Special number': 0.1}], 
   [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'BB', 'Special number': 0.15}],
   [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'CC', 'Special number': 0.05}]
]

nested.sort(key=nested_itemgetter(1, 'Special number'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a shameless plug, but I've had a similar problem enough times that I've written a general purpose item and attr getter. You can find it at [`haggis.recipes.chained_getter`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.recipes.chained_getter). The source is available on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/madphysicist/haggis/-/blob/b8ca8ad91bb806cd6c13b4b971dc6dacd510fed2/src/haggis/recipes.py#L558).

Since non-numerical indices can contain truly arbitrary contents (like slice objects and tuples), I opted for a format string with placeholders rather than trying to parse those objects or forcing users to escape strings. As a shortcut, integer indices can be placed directly in the format string since they can be parsed unambiguously. In your particular use-case, you have a numerical index and a string index, which would look like this:

```
nested.sort(key=chained_getter('[1][]', 'Special number'))
```

OR

```
nested.sort(key=chained_getter('[][]', 1, 'Special number'))
```

The nifty thing here is that you could also extract attributes from the intervening objects.