# itemgetter for nested dict key value

Tags: python

I'd like to get a nested dict value with `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

dct = {"name": {"en": "John"}}
getter = itemgetter("name", "en")
getter(dct)
```

The code gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/sa/разное.py", line 5, in <module>
    getter(dct)
KeyError: 'en'
```

How should I use `itemgetter` to make it work?

Comment: I direct you to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77989045/2988730

Comment: `itemgetter` cannot get nested keys.

Comment: Well, `itemgetter("en")(itemgetter("name")(dct))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could go with functools reduce function

```py
from functools import reduce, partial

dct = {"name": {"en": "John"}}
keys = ["name", "en"]
reduce(dict.get, keys, dct)
```

output:

```
Jonh
```

as a partial function

```
def get_itemgetter(keys):
    def partial_func(dtc):
        return reduce(dict.get, keys, dtc)
    return partial_func

itemgetter = get_itemgetter(keys)
itemgetter(dct)
```

Comment: Throw in a `partial`, and you've got an `itemgetter` equivalent…

Comment: Interestingly since reduce has no keyword arguments I could not make it work with `functools partial` that would have been nice!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that: `getter = partial(reduce, dict.get, ['name', 'en'])`, `getter(dct)`…

Comment: I wa surprised when I tested that but I got this error,: `TypeError: descriptor 'get' for 'dict' objects doesn't apply to a 'list' object`. (I tested in a juopyter notebbok, not sure if that affeect).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `itemgetter("name", "en")` is attempting to return a tuple containing `(dct["name"], dct["en"])`, not `dct["name"]["en"]`.

The solution is to make your own nested getter. I've written one in [`haggis.recipes.chained_getter`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.recipes.chained_getter). You would use it like this:

```
getter = chained_getter("[][]", "name", "en")
```

The parameters are all positional to be able to handle the fact that indices can be any object. You are not limited to string keys.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, this is not how `operator.itemgetter` supposed to work. You can write your custom one if you want:

```py
def nested_item_getter(*items):
    if not items:
        raise ValueError("You need to pass at least one key")

    def inner(d: dict):
        for item in items:
            res = d[item]
            d = res
        return res
    return inner

dct = {"name": {"en": "John"}}
getter = nested_item_getter("name", "en")
print(getter(dct))
```

output:

```
John
```

Answer (score 1):

You could turn your dictionary into a [omegaconf](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.3_branch/) DictConfig, which is especially build for nested configurations.
https://github.com/omry/omegaconf has  >1.8+ stars on GitHub its not some niche package

```
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
from functools import partial

dct = {"name": {"en": "John"}}
odict = OmegaConf.create(dct) # add flags={'allow_objects':True} if you want non primitive types

# Note OmegaConf has a special grammar to select keys, levels can be separated by `.` for example
omega_itemgetter = partial(OmegaConf.select, key="name.en") 
omega_itemgetter(odict)

# John
```